# RabbitMQ Machine Restart all exchanges, queues, virtual host are gone

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

We have a vulnerability patch applied to our QA box yesterday and machine was restarted. This meant the RabbitMQ Server, and service was also down. When we started the service this morning, and I logged it. It lost all the existing exchanges, queues, virtual host, users.

Not sure what just happened here. Can someone show me a direction?

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Context is Windows System, previous run of RabbitMQ was under LocalAdmin user, then next one under another user.

`%AppData%\RabbitMq\DB` is the default location used by the setup.
Based on information available from microsoft, you can see what APPDATA variable points to, which is user specific.

So if you can check the APPDATA of LocalAdmin, I'm guessing you'll find your missing configuration. To check the value, I ran cmd.exe and in the prompt, I typed echo %APPDATA%

Comment: Hi Olivier, Sorry for providing less information. I just logged into the box to check the file location. I see we are using Default File location, which will be %AppData%\RabbitMq\DB. This doesn't sound right a production system. Another thing i noticed is that the service [RabbitMQ] is running as a LocalAdmin. Now maybe that's the reason all the data was gone. coz I started the new service, and my %AppData%/RabbitMQ/DB is empty. !!!Still Confuses!!!!

Comment: Well you just provided all the information needed I think. Standard information to provide are things like OS, which in your case is Windows (more of a Linux guy myself). Based on information available [from microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749104(v=ws.10).aspx), you can see what APPDATA variable points to, which is user specific. So if you can check the APPDATA of LocalAdmin, I'm guessing you'll find your missing configuration. To check the value, I ran cmd.exe and in the prompt, I typed `echo %APPDATA%`